# how to roll back a kernel ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-16.04

I could not find this easily today so I am putting it here for other people, and myself in 6 months

How do you roll back a kernel in ubuntu LTS 16.04, answered below

Answer (score -1):

do the following steps in order

1. ssh into the box
2. sudo su -
3. count the menu and submenu lines to get to the kernel you want to boot, indexed at 0
4. edit /etc/default/grub
5. change GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT="M>N" and save

   - M is menu count
   - N is submenu count, the kernel you want to boot
   - ON 16.04 you start counting N when you get here: submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu'
6. update-grub
7. systemctl reboot
8. ssh in
9. uname -r to see if you booted to the right kernel
10. sudo su -
11. apt-get  purge linux-headers-version_to_remove and linux-image-version_to_remove
12. edit /etc/default/grub and change to: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
13. systemctl reboot
14. ssh in and uname -r to see if you are good

orignal article https://www.calazan.com/how-to-set-an-older-kernel-version-as-the-default-in-grub-during-bootup-ubuntu-12-04/

**If you do this wrong you may not be able to boot the box, be warned**

Comment: you may need to install an older kernel to roll back to the desired state

Comment: Or you can do it in two steps: 1) boot the older kernel. 2) uninstall the unwanted kernel.

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing, could not find a simpler way to do it on cli, lots of info if you had X running

Comment: forgot to add this was AWS so no console